# Accessing both JavaScript Object key and value

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a mapper which spots identifying words in a string and replaces them with another word. In my case a location identifier with the actual directory location.

---

**My Problem** is on line 8 : `str.replace(x.toString(), keys[x]);`

The value `x` is the value as expected but `keys[x]` returns `undefined`.

```
var keys = {
   "$processes"        : "/processes",
   "$local_resources"  : "/feeds/local"
};

function CoreRoute(str){
   for (var x in keys){
      str.replace(x, keys[x]);
   }
   return str;
}
```

I am developing in the node enviroenment. But I'm pretty sure it's a mistake with my logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strings are immutable in Javascript, so String.replace() can't modify str, it returns a new String with the replacement performed. Change

```
str.replace(x, keys[x]);
```

to

```
str = str.replace(x, keys[x]);
```

End code:

```
var keys = {
    "$processes"       : "/processes",
    "$local_resources" : "/feeds/local"
};

function CoreRoute(str) {
    for (var x in keys) {
        str = str.replace(x, keys[x]);
    }
    return str;
}
```